# How to create this type of layout while loading content?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to know that how to create below types of layouts and its effect while content is loaded.

Here are the sample images: 
1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs0lK.jpg
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkHLo.jpg

I have searched but not fount something like this so kindly do some help.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stackoverflow ! I am not an Android developer, but I know that these loading screens are called "Skeleton Screens", when I searched on Google "Android Skeleton Screen" I found a few GitHub repositories, like this one https://github.com/ethanhua/Skeleton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is class shimmer effect.

There is very good step by step implementation available in blog.

[Content loading shimmer effect](https://www.androidhive.info/2018/01/android-content-placeholder-animation-like-facebook-using-shimmer/)

Let me know for more help

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder Images, which are set within a Layout.

When the Image is loaded, the placeholder Image gets replaced by the new Image.

This is used to Show some Content or layout even when not everything is fully loaded

something like

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
```

gets replaced with a new Drawable which is loaded online or from a file in Background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Skeleton layout for this in xml . it is very easy to use.

https://github.com/Faltenreich/SkeletonLayout